# Target buttons in an iframe?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing an Android Web catalog, and for that reason I had to use iframes. I wanted to ask, however, is it possible to click a button in an iframe and make the code work in the main page?

This is the code I have:

```
     function initFastButtons() {
        new FastButton(document.getElementById("CloseButton"), runclose);
        new FastButton(document.getElementById("OpenButton"), runopen);
     };
     function runclose() {
        $('.full-preview-viewer').hide();
     };
     function runopen() {
        $('.full-preview-viewer').show();
     };
```

And this is what a button in an iframe looks like:

```
<input id="OpenButton" type="image" src="products/special/product1.png" name="image" width="336" height="593"></input>
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the definitions for "runclose()" and "runopen()" to your parent window (the document that is creating the iframe).  Then, in your iframe you can modify your initFastButtons() setup to reference those functions as "parent.runclose" and "parent.runopen".  Note that normally this sort of thing is limited when the pages are not requested from the same domain.

Consider these two pages, "inner.html" and "outer.html":

outer.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.do_action = function () {
    alert('the button was clicked!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="inner.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

inner.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(parent.do_action);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Jason, I'm a little confused. I created a separate jquery code in the [iframe](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/mobile7/special.html) which executes a function, that executes `parent.runopen();`. But that doesn't work (it also doesn't work on PC's either, but that's normal). [Here's the main page](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/mobile7)

Answer (score 0):

You can click a button inside an iframe using the following technique.

```
var $currentIFrame = $('#IFrameId');
$currentIFrame.contents().find("#OpenButton").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Hi Starx, I think that this code will however eliminate my FastButton function, which serves to disable the 300ms wait on android devices when pressing buttons.